# jquery autocomplete how to restore value on blur?

Tags: autocomplete, restore, blur

I tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.aComplete').each(function(){

        var inputField = $(this);

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source   :"index.php?action=acomplete&name="+$(this).attr("name"),
            minLength:1
        })

        //clear the input on click
        .focus(function(){
            if(inputField.val(undefined) != true){
                temp = inputField.val();
                inputField.val(undefined);
        }
        inputField.data("autocomplete").search(inputField.val());

        //restore initial value if nothing was typed
        }).blur(function(){
            //check if field is empty and restore value from `temp` if so
            alert(temp); //this shows empty string
        });
    });
});
```

But, the *funny* thing is my variable `temp` becomes an empty string when I call it on blur event.

Why is this happening and how can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

found the glitch, though I can't fully explain myself...
I just moved `temp = inputField.val();` above `if(inputField.val(undefined) != true){` and it worked.